# Latest tomcat-embed-logging-juli does not match with other embedded artifacts.. Is it not part of tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat-juli

I'm working on a legacy maven project and it uses embedded tomcat. Recently as part of fixing the security vulnerabilities, tomcat is upgraded to latest version 9.0.55. But surprisingly I don't see the corresponding version for the artifact `tomcat-embed-logging-juli`. We've already have the slf4j logging library for project. Do I really need the library tomcat-embed-logging-juli dependency as I don't have any logs written with servletContext log?
Following is the relevant section from my pom.xml

```
<properties>        
    <tomcat.version>9.0.55</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.53</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just learning Java & it's dependencies.  I ran into this issue when trying to follow this [Oracle Template](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html). I got this error:

```bash
Dependency 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:10.0.20' not found
```

So did some digging and It appears as though the [original repo: org.apache.tomcat.embed » tomcat-embed-logging-juli](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli) lost support or moved to the core repo as the last update was for 7.0.109 in APR, 2021.

Which leads me to believe that this moved to the core tomcat:
[Maintained Repo: org.apache.tomcat » tomcat-juli](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli)

So, I was able to get a new repo working using the following:

```xml
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  <tomcat.version>10.0.20</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Again I am no expert, just an observation from basic research.  Please let me know if this is wrong or needs adjustment.

Using:

```json
IntelliJ IDEA: 2022.1.4
Java: 18
Tomcat: 10.0.20
Maven: 4.0.0
Maven Compiler: 1.7
```